# Failed to instantiate module firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm requiring my modules via npm. Everything seems to be loading in correctly (angular etc.) except for Firebase. I'm getting this error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module firebase due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'firebase' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

I'm requiring Firebase just like my other modules. This is what my code looks like:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  var angular = require('angular');
  var angularRoute = require('angular-route');
  var angularTouch = require('angular-touch');
  var Firebase = require('firebase');

  angular.module('outcomesApp', ['ngTouch', 'ngRoute', 'firebase'])
  .controller('UnitController', ['$scope', '$http', 'FBURL', function($scope, $http, FBURL){

  }])
  .constant('FBURL', 'https://new-outcomes.firebaseio.com/')
})();
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This error is pretty straightforward. Angular says it can't find that module, so my first question is what scripts are you referencing on your page?

Comment: Just an `app.js` file. I'm using browserify to bundle that script file.

Comment: Don't you need a seperate script library, angularfire, for firebase to [work with angular](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html)?

Comment: So, angularfire is required to work with angular? Sorry, I've come from an over-reliance on tools like Yeoman, and am trying to get my own dev stack  working. So sorry if it's a silly question.

Comment: Yeah. The angular module is in the AngularFire library. That's why you're the `nomod` error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a reference to the [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) library. That is where the angular module is defined.